# How to prevent share session over subdomains in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session

Hello I have a multi tenant application based on subdomains. Each client has own subdomain and database.

I set database name based on subdomain and connect it by middleware.

I use file as session driver. I discovered that if user login sub1.domain.com, then user copies laravel_session value to `sub2.mydomain.com`. If there is a user with the same ID in the database, site allows user in.

How do I prevent this happening?

Using database driver is a solution but I don't want to use it.

Comment: What's the question here? What have you done so far?

Comment: did you use your own authentication code or built-in from laravel? *I set database name based on subdomain and connect it by middleware.* what the middleware do? it do smells like app specific problem..

Comment: I use built-in from laravel , each subdomain uses same session storage folder ( one application ) . If I copy cookie from sub1.mydomain.com to sub2.mydomain.com , I can login to sub2.mydomain.com If there is a user with same ID in sub2 database. Sorry for my english

Comment: @PanelMaker, its application specific and we cant trivially replicate your problem. we cant exactly help you without you helping us able to recreate the problem or inspect the code. your best bet is to have the session stored in database given each tenant had their own database already. perhaps you can try a proper multi-tenancy library such as [Tenancy](https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant).

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to specify the domain value in [session.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L156) as an environment variable, so for one of your clients your **.env**:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=sub2.mydomain.com
```

Comment: I use one application folder, so there is only one .env file. Sub domains share same session storage folder, this is cause the problem.

Comment: Are you saying you have one application for multiple clients, with multiple users?

Comment: Yes , I have one application , seperate by subdomains , each subdomain connects its own database.  Like I said they share same session storage folder so If I copy cookie from sub1 to sub2  it let me in .